# Programming for atg back end code

Tags: java, atg

I am new to atg. I have seen one java code for payment enrollment. I want to know about two functions isLoggingDebug() and logDebug(), Is it custom functions or not?

Comment: A google query would've solved that problem. Really poor quality...

Answer (score 0):

These functions are both not custom, but provided by the SDK

See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23095_01/Platform.93/apidoc/atg/nucleus/logging/ApplicationLoggingImpl.html#isLoggingDebug()

and

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23095_01/Platform.93/apidoc/atg/nucleus/logging/ApplicationLoggingImpl.html#logDebug(java.lang.String)

Comment: @jww The question is answered with the first line of this answer, the links are just extra reference. Copy pasting the code from the link doesn't answer the question any better (in this case)